# What's the difference between 表明 (biǎomíng) and 清楚地表明 (qīngchǔ dì biǎomíng)?

Tags: difference, adverbs

A [Jukuu.com](http://www.jukuu.com/show-%E6%B8%85%E6%A5%9A-6.html) example sentence:

> 图14．34清楚地表明了这一点。
>    Figure 14.34 illustrates this point rather nicely.
>   <sub>Tú 14.34 qīngchǔ dì biǎomíngle zhè yīdiǎn.</sub>

Breaking this apart:

- [图](http://dict.cn/%E5%9B%BE)14．34 (tú 14.34) = Figure 14.34
- [清楚](http://dict.cn/%E6%B8%85%E6%A5%9A) (qīngchǔ) = clear
- [地](http://dict.cn/%E5%9C%B0) (dì) = -ly (turning "clear" into the adverb "clearly")
- [表明](http://dict.cn/%E8%A1%A8%E6%98%8E) (biǎomíng) = to make clear
- [了](http://dict.cn/%E4%BA%86) (le) = (past tense marker)
- [这](http://dict.cn/%E8%BF%99) (zhè) = this
- [一点](http://dict.cn/%E4%B8%80%E7%82%B9) (yīdiǎn) = a little

So maybe my translation would be "Figure 14.34 clearly makes clear this a little."  However, the repetition of "clear" in 清楚地表明 seems strange.

**Question**: What's the difference between 表明 and 清楚地表明?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

清楚地 (adv) = clearly

表明 (v) = show/ demonstrate/ indicate

> *Question: What's the difference between 表明 and 清楚地表明?*

图14．34 **表明**了这一点。= Figure 14. 34 **indicated** this point

图14．34 **清楚地表明**这一点 = Figure 14. 34 **clearly indicated** this point

Comment: Ah, it looks like I also mistook 一点 for "a little", when it means "a point" in this setting.

Answer (score 1):

表明 only means:

> to make known, to state, to disclose

表明态度 for instance means to show ones attitude or state ones attitude.

It doesn’t necessarily mean that you did it in a **clear** way.

清楚地 means

> clearly

oxford translates 清楚地表明 as:

> clearly indicat(ed)

Or as a

> clear signal